# Get List properties using PowerShell

Tags: 2010, list, powershell

I am new in PowerShell. I am trying to print the Library title using PowerShell script. The Library names are stored in XML.

```
<Config>
  <Libraries>
    <LibraryName>
      Test Library 1
    </LibraryName>
    <LibraryName>
      Test Library 2
    </LibraryName>
      </Libraries>
</Config>
```

The Powershell script is as below:

```
$xmlPath=Read-Host 'Enter xml file physical path:'
$xmlinput = [xml](get-content $xmlPath)
$item = $xmlinput.Config  
$AllLibraries = $item.Libraries

foreach($webApp in $AllLibraries.ChildNodes)
{
    try
    {
        $web = Get-SPWeb "Site URL"
        $LibraryName = $webApp.InnerText
        $list = $web.Lists[$LibraryName]
        Write-Host -NoNewline $list.Title
    }
    catch [Exception]
    {
      Write-Host -NoNewline $_.Exception.GetType().FullName, $_.Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Red
    }
    Write-Host
}
```

When I write `$list = $web.Lists["Test Library 1"]` then it worked fine, but when I try to access like this `$list = $web.Lists[$LibraryName]` then it gives nothing.

What may I missing?

Comment: Insert  "Write-Host  $LibraryName" to check your value.

Comment: That was perfectly displayed the name of library. But I got the solution by applying Trim function at the end. There might be issue with extra space in xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just modify one line and your issue will be resolved:

> $list = $web.Lists[$LibraryName.Trim()]

Comment: Hey you guessed perfectly true. But can you please let you know me how you thought of this mistake?

Comment: It's not guess dear.. i have tested your powershell in my environment and after some testing and printing some lines, i have realised that some spaces are there.. so trimmed it..